# Как сделать воксели на opengl? с++

Tags: visual-c++

Не понимаю, от чего отталкиваться, т.е. вообще мне нужно сделать печень, но это сложновато и я решил что то попроще сделать, может хотя бы шар, но это не вопрос.

Собственно вопрос, как лучше всего сделать воксели на opengl С++? Т.е есть какая-нибудь встроенная библиотека на opengl или это делается вручную - рисуем сначала кубики, а затем из них 3Д объект?